# NHibrenate Could Not Load Type

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm getting some very strange behavior with Linq to nHibernate.
I can retrieve all objects I want and I can add where clauses.

But in a very specific case I get the following exception:

> Could not load type x.Foo.Bar.Bars. Possible cause: the assembly was
>   not loaded or not specified.

`x.Foo.Bar.Bars` is part of a piece of lambda expression in a where clause.

Where Bars is a collection of objects. The collection get filled perfectly when I just query without the where clause.

```
 query.Where(x => x.Foo.Bar.Bars.Any(b => b.Name == "BarName"));
```

The stacktrace is this:

> at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.ClassForFullName(String classFullName)

And yes, my mapping files are embedded resources.

Part of the mapping:

```
<bag name ="Bars" inverse="true" lazy="false"
     cascade="none" optimistic-lock="false"
     access="Framework.NHibernate.Properties.EntityCollectionAccessor, Assembly">
  <key column="BagId" />
  <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: What is passed as `classFullName` to that NHibernate method? And which version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: nHibernate version : 3.1.0.4000. I think the classFullName is x.Foo.Bar.Bars.

Comment: There have been many fixes in the Linq provider in the last few versions. You could try 3.3.3.CR1 (or even the current 4.0.0.Alpha1 from the master branch) if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Updated to 3.3.1.4000, and it works now. But I'll keep the question open if there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

`access="Bars, Assembly"` looks wrong. You don't want to define an access strategy that is implemented in the class `Bars`, do you?